# Software to convert list of addresses into latitude and longitude

Tags: geography

I have a list of nearly 5,000 US addresses, in the format Street, City, and ZIP, like so:

[image]

I can, of course, manually enter the address into say Google Maps, then right-click, click "What's Here", and get the latitude and longitude. But with so many addresses, this would take a long time.

Is there any simple and free program that will help me bulk convert these addresses to their latitude and longitude? (I have found a few websites that do this but all have restrictions or charge for it.)

Added: I use Windows 10. Ideally I should be able to just copy paste a list of addresses and it'll convert. Or it can take a CSV file and convert.

Comment: What OS should the software run on? What format should it read from? I guess it could e.g. be done with a tiny little shell/php script on Linux (that way I do the opposite, i.e. looking up a list of lat/lon pairs and convert them into addresses using the OSM API).